# Creaking sound when turning and accelerating in low gear

Tags: renault

So I drive a 2007 clio 1.2  with 75k miles.

What seems to be the issue is when I'm in 1st or 2nd gear and turning left or right and pressing on the accelerator at the same time, there's this awful creaking noise.

It sounds like its coming from the back of the car.

Also to note, iv recently had brake disks an pads changed on all sides and coil spring changed on drivers side. I need replace the one on the passengers side but this noise has been there for months on end.

any help would be GREATLY appreciated as mechanics iv taken it too don't seem to have a clue!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!